# I have downloaded 12.04 but I cannot install it. How to do it?

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-xp

I have downloaded 12.04. I am using Windows XP and I want to install Ubuntu in XP, but the problem is I am not able to start the Ubuntu installation process.

I downloaded Ubuntu from ubuntu.com only. What I downloaded isn't an iso image, it was a zip folder, and when I unzipped it, I found many folders in there, but there wasn't any .iso image in it. So now how am  I supposed to install Ubuntu?

Comment: do you see wubi.exe in the extracted part?

Comment: Hi i think you might be enabled your RAR to open ISO also while installing .

Answer (score 0):

You must create image on CD, for example run NERO or other tool to create CD, that will be readed by bootloader. Check Your booting options.

But first of all when I trying to download Ubuntu 12.04 (Desktop or Server) from http://www.ubuntu.com/ it will download ISO file. Try this again, because Your Zip can be a WUBI for example, or other instalation option.

Answer (score 0):

As Mazeryt has explained ... 
Explaining a little further...
Once you have burnt the ISO to a CD. If you wish to install ubuntu within windows, insert your Ubuntu CD and you will see WUBI.exe on the CD to install. 
There is lots on info on the net for you about WUBI
Another option if you dont have any CD's is to use USB creator

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

which you can then boot from

Hope this is of help